# How can I see the command history across all PowerShell sessions in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

Where can you view the full history from all sessions in Windows Server 2016?

The following PowerShell command only includes the commands from the current session:

```
Get-History
```

Answer (score 346, accepted):

In PowerShell enter the following command:

```
(Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

This gives you the path where all of the history is saved. Then open the path in a text editor.

Try `cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath` to list the history in PowerShell.

Comment: By default it won't be there. You have install module or snapin for it

Comment: You have to use the PSReadline module for it. Or Azure Active Directory module or sharepoint snapin I believe. It is there in powershell gallery.

Comment: Actually, it was there by default on a fresh install of Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Yes. It will be there for sure in Server 2016 but not in the below versions.

Comment: It was in my Windows 10 Pro (1703). But I don't know if it was there by default or if there has been some module installed by Visual Studio or other similar tools. Still, it helped me, after my lates bluescreen.

Comment: It was there by default on Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit.

Comment: basically use simply `cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath` to get the whole history. thank you @DanielLeach

Comment: I suggest explicitly adding the versions of Windows this works on (Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016?).

Comment: Use `cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath | select -Last 10` to get the last 10 lines. Useful if you have many commands in your history.

Comment: Why isn't this the default behavior for the history cmd?

Comment: @DanielLeach don't mind me, Just doing the bad practice of using the comment section to say.. THANKS.  //Wishes from sweden.

Comment: Any idea how to change this command into a (shorter) alias?

Comment: Is it possible to feed the command history of VSCode with this data?

Comment: @wero026 The current history command can optionally display more information on the commands from the current session. For instance: `> (get-history)[-1] | select *time*`.

Answer (score 24):

For getting full history from PowerShell and save the output to file I use this command:

```
Get-Content (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath > D:\PowerShellHistory.txt
```

Comment: Getting the contents of the history file and dumping it to another file seems a bit superfluous. You could just do `copy (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath d:\PowerShellHistory.txt`

Answer (score 15):

On windows PowerShell

To get in a session you can use
`h` or `history`

but to get all commands written in the computer you use

`cat (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath`

Answer (score 11):

Since you are on windows you can also use below to open 'notepad' with it.

```
notepad (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

Answer (score 6):

There's mention of Windows Server/Enterprise editions, but as a Pro (standard retail version) user `HistorySavePath` is also available to me. I needed to see what python packages were recently installed in an older session and wanted to add an answer here for people looking for *specific* things in the history.

```
# if you like file names and line numbers included in your output
Select-String "<search pattern>" (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath

# if you Just want the text without any of the other information
Get-Content (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath | Select-String "<search pattern>"
```

In my case I ran

```
Select-String 'pip install' (Get-PSReadlineOption).HistorySavePath
```

which gave me a list of pip install commands run from my previous sessions

```
...
[Path/To/File]:10401:pip install dash
[Path/To/File]:10824:pip install -r .\requirements.txt
[Path/To/File]:11296:pip install flask-mysqldb
[Path/To/File]:11480:pip install Flask-Markdown
[Path/To/File]:11486:pip install pygments
[Path/To/File]:11487:pip install py-gfm
[Path/To/File]:11540:pip install bs4
```

Answer (score 1):

The Psreadline module 2.1 beta1 on Powershell gallery (Powershell 7 only) https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSReadLine/2.1.0-beta1 does intellisense on the commandline using the saved history:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/1468  It's been starting to show up in Vscode.  https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/g33503/completion_on_history_in_vscode/

Also in Psreadline, you can search the saved history backwards with either f8 (after typing something on the command line) or control-R.  Get-psreadlinekeyhandler lists the key bindings.

```
get-psreadlinekeyhandler -bound -unbound | ? function -match history
```

Comment: Is there a way to execute a previous command from history by giving its ID? Like with bash, you enter `history`, say you want to run command 20 again, then you just do `!20`.

Comment: @leo not that I know of, here's the docs, and you can look at the key bindings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [PowerShell Command History](https://github.com/MaciejTrudnos/PowerShell-Command-History)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).